# Как сделать так чтобы один флекс котейнер наезжал на другой?

Tags: css, http

Как сделать так чтобы один флекс котейнер наезжал на другой?
Что то вроде этого [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Уже нашёл статейку
https://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/nalozhit-elementy-drug-na-druga-s-pomoschyu-css.html
Если кратко чтобы наезжал пишите наезжающему флексу

```
   .megadub {
   position: absolute;
   top: 200px;
   left: 60px;
 }
```

Comment: Чем вам отрицательный margin не угодил?